# Apache NiFi - 'unexpected end of stream' error

Tags: apache-nifi

When I call NiFi's API (/flow/about), I get 'unexpected end of stream on' .. in `invokehttp.java.exception.message` flow file's attribute after it passes from InvokeHTTP processor. (NiFi v1.19.1 running on Linux VM).

Other API tools are also failing when I call NiFi's API.

I would like to use NiFi API, but I suspect that something is not working properly in this version.
(Examples: (1) HTTP GET to google.com is working properly, (2) I receive some raw content from the browser when I call http://localhost:8443/nifi/flow/about)

Could you please advise?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update #20230130#1**

Some errors in nifi-user.log:
[image]

No errors in nifi-app logs:
[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in the nifi-user.log or nifi-app.log? Please check in the logs directory under <NIFI_HOME>.

Comment: @MattGilman I see some errors in nifi-user.log. I updated the topic with some new images.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I learned that in order to make any calls to NiFi by Rest API, I have to use a token for access (before of this I supposed that this is optional).

I was able to get the token and use it in subsequent calls to "**nifi-api**".

I'm expecting that the same procedure is going to work also in the latest NiFi version (current procedure was tested with NiFi 1.16.3).

[image]

[image]